# how many octets are read from the cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I'm trying to do a simple benchmark to know how many octets are read from the cache in each page of my Rails site. I'm talking about the data retrieve from Rails.cache.

I would like to display something like `123Ko/145Ko` at the bottom of my pages.

Does a gem exist to perform this task or perhaps is there something included in the ruby standard library?

Comment: Which cache are you talking about? There are a lot of them!

Comment: I'm talking about Rails.cache. I update the question!

Comment: @JohnMcKey Which cache do you have configured to use? (What is `Rails.cache.class`?)

Comment: `ActiveSupport::Cache::FileStore`. But (if it's possible) I prefere something working with every `ActiveSupport::Cache`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to subclass the store you're using and extend the protected `read_entry` method declared in `ActiveSupport::Cache::Store`, which `FileStore` and the other caches themselves subclass.

```
FileStoreWithReadTracking < ActiveSupport::Cache::FileStore
  def start_page
    @octets_read = 0
  end

  def octets_read
    @octets_read
  end

  protected

    def read_entry(key, options)
      entry = super(key, options)
      @octets_read += entry.size if entry
      entry
    end
end
```

When starting a page, you can call `start_page` to zero out the octet count. Since `read_entry` is a low-level method used every time the cache tries to perform a read, you can intercept any data read and get its size before returning it. You might have to convert `size` to octets.

To set this as your custom cache store, add `config.cache_store = FileStoreWithReadTracking.new('/path/to/file/store')` to your environment. I think you can subclass all the stores this way.

Comment: It was kind of easy after all! Thanks for pointing me the solution out!